# Loading a Properties File From an External Jar

Tags: java, jar, properties-file

I have a properties file which is present in some external jar.
How do I load this properties file in java, given the path to the external jar? (I know where the prperties file is present inside the jar)

Eg., jar file : /home/jars/abc.jar
  Inside this jar I have prop/abc.properties.

Note that the jar is not present in the classpath ( so I cannot use getResourcesAsStream), rather the path to the jar is obtained at run time.

Answer (score 0):

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("path/to/jarFile.jar");
InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(jarFile.getEntry("path/inside/the/jar/to/propFile.properties"));
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(inputStream);
```